# making combinations of 6 numbers using three pairs from four pairs (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8) in R

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to make combinations of 6 numbers using three pairs from four pairs (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8) in R

```
d<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
dc1<-cbind(d[1:2],d[3:4],d[5:6])
dim(dc1)<-c(1,6)
dc2<-cbind(d[1:2],d[3:4],d[7:8])
dim(dc2)<-c(1,6)
dc3<-cbind(d[1:2],d[5:6],d[7:8])
dim(dc3)<-c(1,6)
dc4<-cbind(d[3:4],d[5:6],d[7:8])
dim(dc4)<-c(1,6)
rbind(dc1,dc2,dc3,dc4)
```

Is it possible to use combn to obtain

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    1    2    3    4    7    8
[3,]    1    2    5    6    7    8
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

I have tried

```
d<-structure(list(d1=c(1,2),d2=c(3,4),d3=c(5,6),d4=c(7,8)),.Names = c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
dc <- combn(d, 3, simplify=FALSE)
for(i in 1:length(dc)){
dim(dc[i])<-c(1,6)
}
```

but it is not working. I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility, starting with the vector 'd':

```
i <- (seq_along(d) + 1) %/% 2
t(combn(unique(i), 3, function(cb) d[i %in% cb]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
# [2,]    1    2    3    4    7    8
# [3,]    1    2    5    6    7    8
# [4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 3):

We can create a grouping variable to `split` and then do the `combn`

```
grp <- as.integer(gl(length(d), 2, length(d)))
out <- do.call(rbind, combn(split(d, grp), 3, simplify = FALSE, FUN = unlist))
dimnames(out) <- NULL
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
#[2,]    1    2    3    4    7    8
#[3,]    1    2    5    6    7    8
#[4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

NOTE: Here, the initial object is just the `vector` created instead of the pre-procesed 'd'.  If we have already separated it to columns, it is much easier as @markus mentioned

```
t(combn(d, 3, FUN =unlist))
```

#### data

```
d <- 1:8
```

Comment: Or if `d` is a `data.frame`: `t(combn(as.list(d), m = 3, FUN = unlist))`

Comment: @markus `combn` can data.frame columns as separate entries `t(combn(d, 3, FUN =unlist))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using the `combination` function from the `gtools` package:

Create a list of your pairs:

```
pair.list <- list(c(1,2), c(3, 4), c(5, 6), c(7, 8))
```

Then create the 4 choose 3 combo matrix:

```
combos <- combination(4, 3)
```

Then use the purrr map function to generate the list of output vectors

```
vec.list <- map(1:4, function(x) unlist(pair.list[combos[x, ]]))
```

Finally convert the list of vectors to a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind, vec.list))
```

The benefit of this strategy is that your tuples can be of any length and have any values.